# Convergence of $\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} - \frac{1}{n+3} + \cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

In general, what does the following series:

$$\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} - \frac{1}{n+3} + \cdots$$

converge to in terms of n?

I understand that the alternating harmonic series converges to $\ln 2$, but I cannot see how it will apply to this series.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What's your approach to this question? Show us what did you do with this problem, so that we can continue with that.

Comment: How do these series differ from alternating harmonic series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the series is

$$S_n=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j}{j+n},$$

where I will assume that $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We start by just shifting the index of summation by $n$ so that

$$S_n=\sum_{j=n}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{j-n}}{j}=(-1)^{n+1}\sum_{j=n}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j}=(-1)^{n+1}\left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j}-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j}\right).$$

Notice that the series to the left in the parenthesis is just the alternating harmonic series, which converges to $\ln 2$. It thus follows that

$$S_n=(-1)^{n+1}\left(\ln 2-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j}\right).$$

Now by @Sil's suggestion, the sum on the right can be expressed as

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j}=H_{n-1}-H_{\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor},$$

where $H_k$ is the $k$'th Harmonic number, which is just defined as

$$H_k=\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{j},$$

and $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the floor function. Thus we have that

$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j}{j+n}=(-1)^{n+1}\left(\ln 2-H_{n-1}+H_{\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}\right).$$

Comment: Sum on the right can be expressed in terms of $n$-th harmonic number $H_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}$, as we have $\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j}=H_{n}-H_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$

Comment: @Sil Thanks,  that makes it a bit nicer, I added your suggestion to my answer